# s:url includeParams="none" with s:select didn't work inside s:form

Tags: java, json, struts2

i have an s:url with s:select inside a s:form and i search to populate my
s:select without sending all the form parameters...

I have looked the documentation and the solution should be the includeParams="none" parameter but it didn't work for me...

Could you help me ?

i wrote that :

```
<s:form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="%{#attr['action']}" id="%{#attr['action']}"
    cssClass="form-horizontal">
<s:textfield key="site.form.champ.nom" name="nom" required="true"/>
<s:url id="listeTypesUrl" action="liste-json" namespace="/site/type" includeContext="false" includeParams="none" escapeAmp="false">
                <s:param name="idSite" value="%{siteCourant.id}"/>
            </s:url>
            <sj:select
                    key="site.form.champ.type"
                    href="%{listeTypesUrl}"
                    name="idType"
                    list="list"
                    formIds=""
                    headerKey="ITEM_VIDE"
                    headerValue="%{getText('site.form.champ.type.prompt')}"
                    listKey="id"
                    listValue="libelle"
                    required="true"
                    />
</s:form>
```

When the select is loading a POST request is send with the parameter "nom"...

How to avoid that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is default behavior, so you can't change it. Serializing the specified form elements might help.

Comment: Thomas Sj : select from struts jquery plugin

Comment: Romain no other solutions ?

Comment: @Thomas A tag is not important.

Comment: @AmiraultTony Another solution would be to add unwanted parameter to the exclude list.

Comment: @Thomas Tagging on question are made based on question not a specific technology used by the question.

Comment: @Thomas Open your eyes where do you see [tag:struts]? Also how could you know that is jquery related, you knew that tag...

Comment: @Thomas So, what does anything with the question? How ever these are different tags to let you know it.

Comment: @Thomas Ok i will test that tomorow. Maybe i can use in this case s : select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the jquery plugin that well but from the docs it seems as if it should be possible to define a second empty form, give it an id and then pass that id to the `formIds` attribute, e.g.

```
<s:form ...>
  <sj:select ... formIds="emptyForm"/>
</s:form>

<s:form id="emptyForm" ...></s:form>
```

That still looks like a hack though.

Comment: it's hack but Work well !